# exclude data result if first value is under 10000

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I extract data from a Penalty Box ip address list in this way

```
grep "" pbdb.black.db | awk '{print $4" "$5}'  | sort -nr
```

it returns a list like this

```
38692 193.111.77.250
36212 193.111.77.231
34192 193.111.77.223
27882 193.111.77.207
21202 193.111.77.122
16000 193.111.78.245
15202 45.91.148.61
15202 45.91.148.61
14340 193.111.78.235
11370 45.91.148.46
10350 193.111.77.85
8487 113.111.48.60
8487 113.111.48.60
7903 193.32.160.152
7458 193.32.160.151
7270 193.32.160.150
6800 193.32.160.149
6202 113.111.55.21   
...
... other data
...
6 118.161.142.167
6 118.161.142.167
2 94.103.64.12
2 94.103.64.12
2 78.188.155.79
2 78.188.155.79
2 196.252.52.24
2 196.252.52.24
2 119.153.102.248
2 119.153.102.248
```

What I have to do to exclude from result data where the first value (before the ip address) is under 10000 to have this result ?

```
38692 193.111.77.250
36212 193.111.77.231
34192 193.111.77.223
27882 193.111.77.207
21202 193.111.77.122
16000 193.111.78.245
15202 45.91.148.61
15202 45.91.148.61
14340 193.111.78.235
11370 45.91.148.46
10350 193.111.77.85
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your post, you could mention samples of input and expected output too, may be we could do this in a single `awk` itself.

Comment: Why `grep "" file`? Did you normaly use some string bertween double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Special case

After `sort -rn`, you could use `sed` this way:

```
 ... | sort -rn | sed '/^[0-9]\{1,4\} /,$d'
```

This will delete lines from first line found with less than 5 digit followed by space, to end of input.

#### More seriously:

Reading your post. I will suggest this:

```
grep "RE" filename | awk '{if ($4 >= 10000) print $4,$5}' | sort -rn
```

Or even doing /RE/ in `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
awk '/RE/{if ($4 >= 10000) print $4,$5}' filename | sort -rn
```

Comment: Avoid using `awk | awk` !! (Note: `awk | sort | awk` will give same result than `awk | awk | sort`.

Comment: /RE/ solution returns nothing to me , do you confirm is it correct ?

Comment: It should be "if ($4 >= 10000)" instead of "if ($4 >= 1000)"

Comment: @gr68 `/RE/` mean **regular expression**: `/string previously used in grep command/`.

Answer (score 2):

By seeing your output looks like you need greater than `10000` values.

```
 awk '$1>9999' Input_file
```

OR

```
your_command |  awk '$1>9999'
```